# MYSQL Combine two results into one

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql queries 
first query having results

**bookmark_id, is_fav, title**

and second query have results like this

**bookmark_id, is_deleted**

Sometimes both have same results or may have different result in count

i want output like as

**bookmark_id, is_fav, title, is_deleted**

Can anybody give me idea, how to do this

Thanks

Comment: @AbdulManaf Please remove the link to w3fools. It's offending ;)

Answer (score 0):

By using joins you can able to get the result. think you have not done any research..

```
mysql> create table book(bookmark_id int primary key,is_fav varchar(10),title varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> create table book1(bookmark_id int unique,is_deleted varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into book values(1,'comic','literature');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into book values(2,'short','philiosphy');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into book1 values(1,'comic');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into book1 values(2,'short');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select a.bookmark_id,a.is_fav,a.title,b.is_deleted from book a,book1 b where a.bookmark_id=b.bookmark_id;
+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
| bookmark_id | is_fav | title      | is_deleted |
+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
|           1 | comic  | literature | comic      |
|           2 | short  | philiosphy | short      |
+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i have three tables

Comment: you can use inner join **SELECT column_list
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1
INNER JOIN t3 ON join_condition2
...
WHERE where_conditions;**

Comment: @Hitu : Post your question properly with proper table structure.